# How do I add green screen footage to another video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

Okay, so I couldn't find this anywhere. I could find only adding green screen footage to an image.
I have a video and a footage that has green screen in the background. I want that video with green screen in the background to add to that video I have. How can I do that? Can somebody suggest me what to google at least. I not completely Blender illiterate, familiar with the basics
And probably, most important, how do I preserve the sound from both videos? Like, I want to play the sound from the base video and at the same time I want to hear sound from that green screen footage

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Green screen removal is a compositing process. The image input node that you use works with single image, image sequence or video files as input so can be used in all scenarios. The same node setup can be used if you are mixing multiple videos or a video and a still image.

In the VSE, the same as mixing video clips, you can place multiple audio tracks in different channels and have them play at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't quite work. I could not get sound to work properly. Plus, if I scaled down too much the green screen video via transform node, it would start adding a black border on overall clip. Then I switched to Adobe Premiere and did it in like 5 minutes

Comment: TBH if you wanted to know what the fastest way to do it was, where cost is  no impediment then we could suggest many alternatives. But you wanted a Blender solution.